# Docusign API Explorer not pre-populating fields

Tags: docusignapi, rest

I tried filling in the tabs with labels and values, but when I send the request the tabs are not pre-populated, also does anyone know how does the fullname tab get populated?

```
{
  "emailSubject": "Welcome to Soul Gym",
  "status": "sent",
  "templateId": "196b0d27-b967-4380-bb2c-013051ec9e45",
  "templateRoles": [
    {
      "clientUserId": "marcus.yeo@business.edu.sg",
      "email": "marcus.yeo@business.edu.sg",
      "name": "Marcus Yeo",
      "roleName": "New Member",
      "tabs": {
        "emailTabs": [
          {
            "tabLabel": "Email",
            "value": "marcus.yeo@business.edu.sg"
          }
        ],
        "fullNameTabs": [
          {
            "tabLabel": "FullName"
          },
          {
            "tabLabel": "FullName2"
          }
        ],
        "textTabs": [
          {
            "tabLabel": "Address",
            "value": "32 Duke Road"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're missing the documentId and tabPositions to display the full name on your document. Here is an example working request body with raw document omitted:

```
{
  "documents": [
    {
      "documentBase64": "<Base64BytesHere>",
      "documentId": "1",
      "fileExtension": "docx",
      "name": "testFile"
    }
  ],
  "emailSubject": "testing envelope",
  "recipients": {
    "signers": [
      {
        "email": "john.doe@example.com",
        "name": "Docusign Test Signer",
        "recipientId": "1",
        "routingOrder": "1",
        "tabs": {
          "fullNameTabs": [
            {
              "documentId": "1",
              "pageNumber": "1",
              "xPosition": "280",
              "yPosition": "172"
            },
            {
              "documentId": "1",
              "pageNumber": "1",
              "xPosition": "480",
              "yPosition": "300"
            }
          ],
          "signHereTabs": [
            {
              "documentId": "1",
              "pageNumber": "1",
              "xPosition": "120",
              "yPosition": "300"
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  "status": "sent"
}
```

And the resulting `fullName` placement shown on a demo document I tried with this request json:

[image: response image]

Though I didn't use an envelope `templateId` here, the mechanism works the same, set the documentID, pageNumber, & x/y coordinates to inject the fullName on your documents. Feel free to check out the [Quickstart tool](https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/quickstart/) as well to find a full DocuSign implementation in a language of your choice that you can modify to suit your needs.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer, but I would like to know if I could fill it based on the tab label instead of the absolute x and y position?